# Obtaining to fetch data from the form using GET Method

Tags: django, ajax

I want to fetch a list of data using ajax function which is called in views.py for the ajax function using GET Method in views.py. But my submit button is not functioning nor it is fetching any data and displaying the result.
Any help will be appreciated.

My codes are:
views.py

```
def home(request):
    majors = Major.objects.filter(percentages__isnull=False).distinct().order_by("pk")

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.GET.get('major1')
        form = request.GET.get('major2')
        form = request.GET.get('major3')
        form = request.GET.get('major4')
        form = request.GET.get('major5')

    line_chart = pygal.Line(width=1500)
    line_chart.title = 'Budget Estimation'  
    context = { 
        "chart": line_chart.render_data_uri(),
        'majors': majors
    }

    return render(request, "website/index.html" , context )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to submit your form data via GET method than you have to change code in your view.py like this

```
if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
```

Comment: Thank you for figuring it , i now have changed it to this if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
 form1 = request.GET.get('major1')
 form2 = request.GET.get('major2')
 form3 = request.GET.get('major3')
 form4 = request.GET.get('major4')
 form5 = request.GET.get('major5')         But when i click the submit button it pops like 127.0.0.1:8000 says undefined